# AngularJS, insert predefined DOM element into html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an predefined Canvas element in every element of `results` array, which I use in `ng-repeat`. I need to place this canvas inside of every element of ng-repeat. `{{result.canvas}}` didn't work and gives an error.
Tried to insert canvas via directives, but without success.

Every element in `results` have a bunch of data and one Canvas DOM element. E.g.:

`result.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");`

And I need to insert this canvas into HTML:

```
<div class="result" data-ng-repeat="result in results" data-ng-if="!result.error">
  <div class="result-image">
    <div class="result-image-display">
      <div data-ng-style="computeStyle(result)">
      {{result.canvas}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Which gives error: `https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bresult.canvas%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&p1=TypeError:%20Converting%20circular%20structure%20to%20JSON`

I need to know how to insert a DOM Element into HTML without getting this error.

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting ? It would also be nice to have your `results` json...

Comment: Its tuff to understand what you mean. Do you mean iterating through DOM elements?

Comment: could show us what you already tried? perhaps put your code (including the results array) in a http://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: I got this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bresult.canvas%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&p1=TypeError:%20Converting%20circular%20structure%20to%20JSON <code>results</code> have a bunch of data, which not necceseary, but it also have an Canvas element, which must be inserted inside of html. Edited the description, to be more clear.

Comment: It looks like you have a problem in your JSON structure and Angular can't deserialize your JSON. It probably is because you are referencing to other variables/objects when declaring your JSON object. This is why it would be nice to have your JSON declaration in there....

Comment: Hey, could you please provider plunker or fiddle? (:

Comment: result.canvas is not an JSON, it's a [Canvas DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas). And i'm need to insert it into an html.

Comment: Yes I get that, so you are assigning it to the JSON object through a JS variable right ? I think the problem might come from here... You shoud have it as a `string` and use `ng-bind-html` to insert it.

Comment: I don't get it. `ng-bind-html` takes an url to an HTML file, and don't takes DOM elements. And what am I need to have as `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular should have executed $interpolate to replace your double-curlies, and $interpolate in the docs says the parameter should be a string. But your canvas is not a string.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: Yes, it's a Canvas DOM Element, and I need to know, how to insert it.

Comment: creating a new directive is one way; in this new directive you can instruct it from which model it should take the element from. using "=attr" maybe; then you can append the canvas element from there.

Comment: Can you provide an example, of how I can do this?

Comment: Which one? on creating a directive?

Comment: How to send the Canvas as attribute to directive.

Comment: you don't send a canvas as an attribute, you tell the directive to bind a parent scope's model to your directive model. you may not need this at all; you can refer to the parent's scope, see prototypal inheritance. angular is using this when creating child scopes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I got it working. (via link:$scope.$parent.result.canvas)

Comment: ok thanks for accepting my answer I was just finished doing an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/oEbyiLTUMBEUkgTnFQKO